# Unusually agitated and constantly sucking two-week old

Tags: behavior, sleep, newborn

Today our two week old was (and still is) unusually agitated. She slept two hours less than her up-until-now average, requested breastfeeding for entire one hour more and was more cry-prone than ever. She has trouble going to sleep, won't sleep on her own, has to either fall asleep on a breast or be cuddled. And when she does sleep, she won't sleep for too long and will soon wake up crying, instead of usual calm looking around or fussing. And she rejects a dummy which she liked before.

We have followed all elements on every newborn checklist we could find. She has no fever. Her clothes seem perfectly comfortable (she wore them few days before). Everything we can think of seems to be in order.

Do such days happen? Is there anything we can do to calm, soothe her?

**EDIT: One day later.**

My daughter seems to have calmed down. She does not seem to have grown yet, but she does seem "smarter" and more agile. She rotates her head more quickly, follows our faces with her eyes more "fluently" (she used to do it, but in large "jumps"). She also spends more time just lying and looking around at the world. I guess she gathered enough experience points and was going through a level-up;)

To sum up, it seems I shouldn't have worried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like your baby has hit her first growth spurt. Expect her to feed more frequently, sleep less and be cranky for a few days, possibly longer. More info here: http://www.whattoexpect.com/first-year/ask-heidi/baby-growth-spurts.aspx

Comment: I'm fairly sure she's had one already, since she grew out of some clothes overnight. She wasn't that cranky then. Could this be the second growth spurt? [Here](http://kellymom.com/bf/normal/growth-spurts/) it says that the second is 2-3 weeks, she's 16 days old now.

Comment: It could be a second growth spurt. All the guides that list ages for infant milestones are approximate; if your baby is exhibiting all the signs of a growth spurt and there is no other obvious reason for her to be awake, cranky and nursing a lot, it's probably a growth spurt. 

The site you linked also brought up a good point that infants might also be cranky and nursing more frequently as they approach developmental milestones. I do remember that happening as well.

Comment: I suggest expanding your answer for the developmental milestone (or add another answer, since it's a different topic). As of right now it seems that that was the reason.